# BreezeJS - issues with export and import

Tags: breeze

I am trying to work as The "Sandbox Editor"

```
function getClonedWorkItem(entityType, entityId) {
        var clonedManager = entityManager.createEmptyCopy();
        var oentity = entityManager.getEntityByKey(_mapEntityTypeToSingleType(entityType), entityId);

        //export it to the new manager
        var exportData = entityManager.exportEntities([oentity], true);
        clonedManager.importEntities(exportData);

        var cloned = clonedManager.getEntityByKey(_mapEntityTypeToSingleType(entityType), entityId);

        return {
            entity: cloned,
            __context: clonedManager
        };
    }
```

the problem is that the cloned item dont have the extrametadata under the aspect, so i cannot sent it to the server to update - as it fails on

```
function updateDeleteMergeRequest(request, aspect, prefix) {
    var extraMetadata = aspect.extraMetadata;
    var uri = extraMetadata.uri || extraMetadata.id;
    if (__stringStartsWith(uri, prefix)) {
        uri = uri.substring(prefix.length);
    }
    request.requestUri = uri;
    if (extraMetadata.etag) {
        request.headers["If-Match"] = extraMetadata.etag;
    }
}
```

Comment: As of BreezeJs version 1.4.13, available now, this has been fixed.